# jQuery File Upload library: how to upload with a click for a SINGLE file

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to this section [jQuery-File-Upload Basic plugin documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin#how-to-start-uploads-with-a-button-click), you can upload file upon a click of a button by using `add`. however, this causes an additional 'Upload' button to be added each time the user select a file, whereas my app only accepts a single upload.

[see JS fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/oq5w3s7a/1/)

so how to achieve this: when user clicks Choose file the 2nd time, that file replaces the initial file and only one upload button is present at any moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a new button is getting added every time the 'Add' event fires with this line:

```
$('<button/>').text('Upload').appendTo(document.body)
```

You can prevent re-adding the button in multiple ways, here's a simple example:

```
if ($("button:contains('Upload')").length == 0) {
    $('<button/>').text('Upload').appendTo(document.body)
}
```

You'll probably have to update the code to rebind the 'click' function with the new data being submitted.